# Why can't I map string with address in solidity?

Tags: solidity, mapping

I want to map names(string) with a wallet address in solidity but solidity throws an error saying that its not allowed!

```
mapping(string => address) public users;
```

And this is the error I get:

```
    TypeError: Dynamically-sized keys for public mappings are not supported.
        mapping(string => address) public users;
        ^-------------------------------------^
```

Is there any other way to do it?

New here! Suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yeah, change the `public` to `internal` or `private`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
mapping(string => address) public users;
```

To this:

```
mapping(string => address) private users;
```

Or to this:

```
mapping(string => address) internal users;
```

And add this if you must:

```
function getUser(string str) public view returns (address) {
    return users[str];
}
```

Comment: Today morning even I was thinking of doing the same and then opened stackexchange to see this. Anyways thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to goodvibration's answer, it has to do with Solidity's inability to automatically construct the inspection function requested with `public` - hence the suggestion to drop it.

It also has to do with the compiler version. Here you can see it works fine with 0.5.11.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.11;

contract StringMap {
    mapping(string => address) public users;
}
```

So, actually you can.

Subject to gas cost testing, I would consider using a `bytes32` instead, and a hash function over any string that might be in play.

```
string x;
bytes32 key = keccak256(bytes(x));
```

Lastly, as a side note, in most cases it would be better to look up users up by their address instead of relying on another input to discover it. `msg.sender` is usually used to reliably authenticate/positively identify the signer.

Hope it helps.